# Display of results is delayed by 5s in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, nsoperation, uisearchdisplaycontroller

My `UISearchDisplayController` performs asynchronous searches via `NSOperationQueue`.

However the results table does not visually update until approximately 5s after the `NSOperation` calls `[searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData]`.

```
- (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController*)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString*)searchString
{
    [searchQueue cancelAllOperations];
    NSInvocationOperation *op = [[[CustomSearchOperation alloc] initWithController:controller searchTerm:searchString] autorelease];
    [searchQueue addOperation:op];

    return NO;
}
```

My CustomerSearchOperation updates the tableView like so:

```
- (void) main
{
    // perform search

    [searchDisplayController setContents:results];
    [searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that UI updates must occur on the main thread, and `reloadData` is being called from a background thread via the `NSOperationQueue`.

You can use the `NSObject` method [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) to ensure such updates occur on the main thread.

```
- (void) main
{
    // perform search

    [sdc setContents:results];
    [sdc.searchResultsTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                withObject:nil
                                waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```